# Sencha touch 2 filterby() not updating records

Tags: touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a nested list on one of the pages of a Tabbed Panel app that is pulling data from "offices.json"

I should like to be able to filter this list when a user clicks on a toolbar button. However my filterBy() function doesn't update the store and the list of offices I can see, even though I can see in the console it is iterating the records and finding a match. What am I doing wrong?
(And yes I have tried doing s.load() both before and after the filterBy to no avail!)

```js
toolbar:{                        
   items:[{
           text: 'Near you',
           id: 'btnNearYou',
           xtype: 'button',
           handler: function() {
             s = Ext.StoreMgr.get('offices');
             s._proxy._url = 'officesFLAT.json';        
             console.log("trying to filter");
             s.filterBy(function(record) {
              var search = new RegExp("Altrincham", 'i'); 
              if(record.get('text').match(search)){
               console.log("did Match");
               return true;
              }else {
               console.log("didnt Match");
               return false;
             }
           });
           s.load();
          }                            
   }]
```

For the record I'm defining my store like so:

```js
store: {
    type: 'tree',
    model: 'ListItem',
    id: 'offices',
    defaultRootProperty: 'items',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        root: {},
        url: 'offices.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No need to recreate the regex each time, cache it outside.
2. You can simplify the code a lot (see below).
3. Why are you calling load directly after? That's going to send it to the server and it will just retrieve the same dataset.

```js
toolbar: {
    items: [{
        text: 'Near you',
        id: 'btnNearYou',
        xtype: 'button',
        handler: function() {
            s = Ext.StoreMgr.get('offices');
            s._proxy._url = 'officesFLAT.json';
            var search = /Altrincham/i;
            s.filterBy(function(record) {
                return !!record.get('text').match(search);
            });
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: I added the code above to the handler function of my button, but nothing happens. The function fires (I can see via console.log) but the nestedList doesn't reload with the filtered records. I can only get something to appear if I call s.load() (Then as you say you get the whole dataset) Is there something I should be setting at the store level perhaps? I'll add it to the main question above....

Comment: I think my problem stems from trying to do this to a NestedList. From scouring the internet it seems that its not possible to Filter a NestedList in Sencha Touch. However if this is a normal List then the code above does work, so thanks Evan!